# Issue with unregistering and registering to a different server

Tags: ios, sybase, sup

I've encountered an issue with registration and unregistering in my app. For Development purposes we have 3 instances of SUP. The following scenario causes ErrorCode 568;

1. Create database & register with UAT Server (Success)
2. Perform an Initial Sync with server (Success)
3. Unregister with UAT Server & delete database (Success)
4. Create database & register with DEV Server (Success)
5. Perform an Initial Sync with server (Success)
6. Unregister with DEV Server & delete database (Success)
7. Create database & register with UAT Server (Fail)

Error Output:

```
[ERROR] [SUPApplication.m:1171] error @ registerApplication MessagingClientException {
    ErrorCode = 568;
    ErrorMessage = "";
}
=================================================
onRegistrationStatusChanged: status = 201, code = 568, message = SUPApplicationError_UNKNOWN
=================================================
[Line 420] Exception: SUPPersistenceException: Sync failed: -1497 (ERROR) %1:3 %2:3004;Parameter 1:3;Parameter 2:3004
```

Attempt 1: I thought calling `[[SUPApplication getInstance] clearApplicationState]` would help but now with the following steps I constantly receive ErrorCode 516;

1. Create database & register with UAT Server (Success)
2. Perform an Initial Sync with server (Success)
3. Unregister with UAT Server & delete database (Success)
4. Create database & register with DEV Server (Fail)

I tried it in reverse and got the same error (Started at DEV and tried to register with DEV)

Error Output:

```
[SUPApplication.m:1171] error @ registerApplication MessagingClientException {
    ErrorCode = 516;
    ErrorMessage = "";
}
=================================================
onRegistrationStatusChanged: status = 201, code = 516, message = SUPApplicationError_REGISTRATION_Resetting Communications
=================================================
[Line 420] Exception: SUPPersistenceException: Sync failed: -1497 (ERROR) %1:3 %2:3004;Parameter 1:3;Parameter 2:3004
```

What I know

- Performing the first two steps and synchronising I am always getting data
- Aside from the connection settings in the MBO on the SCC, both the
  application settings are identical
- I am setting the applicationIdentifier each time I register

I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue before and what the solution was?